# grabbing an Int from a NSTimer's userInfo

Tags: swift

I need to do an `Int` comparison on some data stored in my `NSTimer`'s `userInfo` property. I currently am trying to use the `<` operator on the `userInfo` directly but I get the following error.

```
 Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'AnyObject'
```

I understand why I am getting the error (`userInfo` isn't of type `Int` but of type `AnyObject`). However, everytime I initialize my `NSTimer` I populate its `userInfo` with the following:

```
 NSNumber(integer: nextIndex)
```

I would like to retrieve that `nextIndex` value from my stored version of the `NSTimer` in the following way:

```
        let userInfo = SharingManager.sharedInstance.globalTimer.userInfo

        if (userInfo < 2){ 
           //create new timer
        }else{
           //create a new timer with different properties
         }
```

Any thoughts on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to cast the value, like this:

```
guard let userInfo = SharingManager.sharedInstance.globalTimer.userInfo as? Int else { 
    print("userInfo was not an Int.")
    return
}

if (userInfo < 2) { 
    //create new timer
} else {
    //create a new timer with different properties
}
```